# What kind of optimization problem is this and what tools can be used to find a solution?

Tags: linear-programming, integer-programming

Problem description:
The location of n solar panels is defined by the x,y location of the solar panels. Every solar panel must be protected by an anode. Each anode can protect up to 4 solar panels within a radius r of the anode. Place the anodes at x,y locations such that all solar panels are protected with the minimum number of anodes.

What is the name for this type of problem and what type of codes can be used to answer it?

Through some searching, I have found the terms linear programming and integer programming and seen refences to or-tools. I want to know if is a more specific name for this type of spatial problem to aid in my research.

Comment: Sounds like it could be viewed as a *facility placement* problem, e.g. https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/13658810601169857?journalCode=tgis20

Comment: "Spatial simulated annealing" is a technique that has been effectively applied to such problems for a long time (30 years at least).  It does not require you to discretize the space of solutions, as integer programming usually does.

Answer (score 1):

It's a location-allocation problem, also known as a location problem or a site-selection problem.  @John_Madden's comment popped up as I was typing this, so I'll add facility placement problem to the list as well.  Mixed-integer programming, or in this case just plain integer programming, are common solution techniques.